# Setting proper relative URL

Tags: html

If I am on the following page:
http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department/class/SitePages/Home.aspx
and want to have a link to 
http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department/SitePages/Home.aspx
i.e. I want to keep /sitepages/home.aspx and move it one step up in the hierarchy
and not hard code http://subsite.mysite.com/sites/department/
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `/sites/department/SitesPages/Home.aspx` as target for the `href`

Comment: the reason why I don't want to hard code the first part is beacuse I don't know on beforehand what the department name will be

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<a href="../../SitePages/Home.aspx">My Link</a>` or

```
<a href="/department/SitePages/Home.aspx">My Link</a>
```

Comment: Unfortuneately sharepoint won't let me save a URL starting with ../../ and I don't know on beforehand what the department name will be so I can't use that part either. Thanks anyway